# I'm trying to create hive table from pyspark dataframe but getting error extraneous input '/'

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_340424/container_e366_1606858479635_34
0424_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_340424/container_e366_1606858479635_34
0424_01_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1090.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input '/' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE',
'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'NO', 'EXISTS', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'F
ALSE', 'NULLS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'FOR', 'INTERVAL', 'CASE', 'WHEN', 'THEN', 'ELSE', 'END', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'S
EMI', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'ON', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'UNBOUNDED', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWIN
G', 'CURRENT', 'FIRST', 'AFTER', 'LAST', 'ROW', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'DIRECTORY', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE
', 'INTO', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'FORMAT', 'LOGICAL', 'CODEGEN', 'COST', 'CAST', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTI
TIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'DROP', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'TO', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'STRATIFY', 'ALTER', 'RENAME', 'ARRAY', 'MA
P', 'STRUCT', 'COMMENT', 'SET', 'RESET', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MACRO', 'IGNORE', 'BOTH', 'LEADING', '
TRAILING', 'IF', 'POSITION', 'DIV', 'PERCENT', 'BUCKET', 'OUT', 'OF', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'OVERWRITE', 'TRANSFORM', 'REDU
CE', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'DELIMITED', 'FIELDS', 'TERMINATED', 'COLLECTION', 'ITEMS', 'KEYS', 'ESCAPED', 'LINES', 'SEPARATED', 'FUNCTION', 'EXTENDED', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'LAZY', 'FORMATTED', 'GLOBAL', TEMPORARY, 'OPTIONS', 'UNSET', 'TBLPROPERTIES', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'BUCKETS', 'SKEWED', 'STORED', 'DIRECTORIES', 'LOCATION', 'EXCHANGE', 'ARCHIVE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'FILEFORMAT', 'TOUCH', 'COMPACT', 'CONCATENATE', 'CHANGE', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT', 'CLUSTERED', 'SORTED', 'PURGE', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', DATABASE, DATABASES, 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'COMPUTE', 'LIST', 'STATISTICS', 'PARTITIONED', 'EXTERNAL', 'DEFINED', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'REPAIR', 'RECOVER', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'COMPACTIONS', 'PRINCIPALS', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'LOCKS', 'OPTION', 'ANTI', 'LOCAL', 'INPATH', IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
/dev/07681/app/BAP0/EWST/sample/parquet_3/
^^^

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parseTableIdentifier(ParseDriver.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:393)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EDW_sas_to_parq.py", line 142, in <module>
    sas_to_df.write.format("hive").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(tbl)
  File "/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_340424/container_e366_1606858479635_340424_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 744, in saveAsTable
  File "/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_340424/container_e366_1606858479635_340424_01_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_340424/container_e366_1606858479635_340424_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 73, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: "\nextraneous input '/' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'NO', 'EXISTS', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'NULLS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'FOR', 'INTERVAL', 'CASE', 'WHEN', 'THEN', 'ELSE', 'END', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'SEMI', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'ON', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'UNBOUNDED', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWING', 'CURRENT', 'FIRST', 'AFTER', 'LAST', 'ROW', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'DIRECTORY', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'INTO', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'FORMAT', 'LOGICAL', 'CODEGEN', 'COST', 'CAST', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'DROP', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'TO', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'STRATIFY', 'ALTER', 'RENAME', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'STRUCT', 'COMMENT', 'SET', 'RESET', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MACRO', 'IGNORE', 'BOTH', 'LEADING', 'TRAILING', 'IF', 'POSITION', 'DIV', 'PERCENT', 'BUCKET', 'OUT', 'OF', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'OVERWRITE', 'TRANSFORM', 'REDUCE', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'DELIMITED', 'FIELDS', 'TERMINATED', 'COLLECTION', 'ITEMS', 'KEYS', 'ESCAPED', 'LINES', 'SEPARATED', 'FUNCTION', 'EXTENDED', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'LAZY', 'FORMATTED', 'GLOBAL', TEMPORARY, 'OPTIONS', 'UNSET', 'TBLPROPERTIES', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'BUCKETS', 'SKEWED', 'STORED', 'DIRECTORIES', 'LOCATION', 'EXCHANGE', 'ARCHIVE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'FILEFORMAT', 'TOUCH', 'COMPACT', 'CONCATENATE', 'CHANGE', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT', 'CLUSTERED', 'SORTED', 'PURGE', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', DATABASE, DATABASES, 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'COMPUTE', 'LIST', 'STATISTICS', 'PARTITIONED', 'EXTERNAL', 'DEFINED', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'REPAIR', 'RECOVER', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'COMPACTIONS', 'PRINCIPALS', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'LOCKS', 'OPTION', 'ANTI', 'LOCAL', 'INPATH', IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\n/dev/07681/app/BAP0/EWST/sample/parquet_3/\n^^^\n"
```

```
tbl = "/dev/07681/app/BAP0/EWST/sample/parquet_3/"
sas_to_df.write.format("hive").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(tbl)
```

Please either resolve this or let me know how can I do the same in any other way.

====NEW log===

```
sas_to_df.write.format("hive").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(hive_tbl_nm[c], path=tbl)
  File "/disk/disk18/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_348291/container_e366_1606858479635_348291_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 744, in saveAsTable
  File "/disk/disk18/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_348291/container_e366_1606858479635_348291_01_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/disk/disk18/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_348291/container_e366_1606858479635_348291_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/disk/disk18/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_348291/container_e366_1606858479635_348291_01_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1091.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tez/dag/api/SessionNotRunning when creating Hive client using classpath: file:/disk/disk18/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_348291/container_e366_1606858479635_348291_01_000001/__app__.jar, file:/disk/disk18/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_348291/container_e366_1606858479635_348291_01_000001/spark-sas7bdat-2.1.0-s_2.11.jar, file:/disk/disk18/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_348291/container_e366_1606858479635_348291_01_000001/parso-2.0.11.jar, file:/disk/disk18/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/appcache/application_1606858479635_348291/container_e366_1606858479635_348291_01_000001/, file:/disk/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/DL600SRVHDP/filecache/4965/__spark_conf__.zip/, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/JavaEWAH-0.3.2.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/ST4-4.0.4.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/activation-1.1.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/core-1.1.2.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/aircompressor-0.8.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/httpclient-4.5.2.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/curator-client-2.7.1.jar,, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/antlr4-runtime-4.7.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/hppc-0.7.2.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/commons-compiler-3.0.8.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/jpam-1.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/derby-10.12.1.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/arrow-format-0.8.0.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/eigenbase-properties-1.1.5.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/arrow-memory-0.8.0.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/flatbuffers-1.2.0-3f79e055.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/arrow-vector-0.8.0.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/httpcore-4.4.4.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/avro-1.7.7.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/ivy-2.4.0.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/guava-14.0.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/gson-2.2.4.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.6.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/guice-3.0.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/jta-1.1.jar, file:/disk/disk12/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1116799/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/ext
/cldrdata.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-o
penjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib
/ext/localedata.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java
-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/j
re/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/usr
/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSe
ssionStateBuilder.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.tableExists(SessionCatalog.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:398)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:393)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:270)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tez/dag/api/SessionNotRunning
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:529)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:116)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tez.dag.api.SessionNotRunning
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.doLoadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.loadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:216)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the path using `path=...`. Do not put the path as the table name.

```
tbl = "/dev/07681/app/BAP0/EWST/sample/parquet_3/"
sas_to_df.write.format("hive").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable('table_name', path=tbl)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1091.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: @coder please show the complete error traceback by editing your question. It's likely that you've missed some jar files, but we need to see the traceback to know which one is missing.

Comment: please check, I have added. Do we have any other way to create hive table from pyspark dataframe?

Comment: @coder as the error says, "Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars."